# How to take input for running YOLO model when My flask model runs?

Tags: python, flask, yolo

I am trying to work a yolo model(the yolo model already works independently!) with Flask application. But as soon as the flask server runs. My  Model doesnt work. My YOLO model detects objects from the video and when run independently it needs inputs, outputs and yolo-coco to be typed along while compiling. But during Flask server running it goes on throwing up errors continuously like -Yolo models needs --input --output --yolo. How to use this command when I run flask app so that my application along with YOLO model runs smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to start YOLO as a new process from within Flask, using a python built-in library and then establish a process-level communication between Flask and YOLO.

For instance, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html allows you to send std input to a new spawned process, as well as reading the std output from it.